# importing a pygame event into another script

Tags: python, events, import, pygame

I am trying to import a pygame script into another script in order to organize it better (making a 'main' script). One of the functions I am using in my first script is dependent on an event I would want to define in my second script.

**script 1**

```
def move(manholes , location,  n):      
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT :
        x = manholes[n+1][0] - manholes[n][0]
        y = manholes[n+1][1] - manholes[n][1]  
        grad = y/x
```

**script2**

```
while True :     
    for event in pygame.event.get() : 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT :               
            pygame.quit()
            quit()      
             
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:        
        n , location = sense(location , n)                     
        if n == length:    
            print('fine') 
            manholes.reverse() 
            n = 0 
            location = (manholes[0][0] , manholes[0][1])            
        else :            
            location  = move(manholes, location, n)
```

is there a way to import the event back into the original script or define it back into the first script?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the event object by an argument. e.g:

Function in script 1:

```py
def move(keydown_event, manholes, location, n):
    if keydown_event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        # [...]
```

Call function in script 2:

```py
while True :     
    for event in pygame.event.get() : 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT :               
            pygame.quit()
            quit()      
             
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  
            # [...]

            location = move(event, manholes, location, n)
```